# How to install georeferencer plugin in QGIS 3.28.1-Firenze?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I would like to use the Georeference plugin in QGIS 3.28.1-Firenze on my macbook.

The *Georeference GDAL* plugin doesn't exist in the list of available plugins.  (I only see *Freehand raster georeferencer* )

I have also read that this plugin is automatically preinstalled in latest QGIS version but I have no clue where I can find it.  It doesn't appear under the raster menu as you can see:

[image]

Comment: As my colleague always says: "Google is your friend" (https://www.google.com/search?q=qgis+georeferencer+missing) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now under « layer » menu, not anymore under « raster » cause since 3.26 (or 3.28), you can also georeference vector layers!